# How do you use the word "arguably"?

Tags: word-usage

Does *arguably* mean "something could be argued", or "could be arguable, is debatable or questionable"? But more often it seems to emphasize an adjective, for example:

> It is arguably the best, the finest, the most powerful, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think of it as a strong term to use at the front of a sentence indicating some case may be made. I would generally use it when I have an opinion but am allowing for doubt.

*Arguably, baseball is **the** American sport.*

*Certainly, baseball is a dominant sport in America.*